# wireless networking portable devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have CenturyLink 9005 modem/router, my house is large enough that i also have a Netgear extender to use wireless devices in other rooms. The wireless signal, to my Kindle Fire Hd and/or IPods and others device does not work very well in many of the rooms. what can i do to be able to use these wireless devices anywhere in my home?

Answer (score 0):

There may not be anything you can do short of putting additional repeaters or multiple WAP's throughout out the house. It depends heavily on the construction materials used.  I have a split level house with a metal roof. The upstairs areas of my house have a very poor signal from the WAP that is downstairs. I have practically no signal in the basement.  I resolved by adding a WAP upstairs and just don't use wireless in the basement.